# Are there poor practices in this use of python cryptography package to generate RSA keypair?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, python-cryptography

Use case: I want to generate no-passphrase 2048-byte RSA keypairs I can use for service accounts to authenticate to Snowflake. I need to generate them programmatically to make key rotation practical.

Snowflake docs provide [a manual procedure using OpenSSL at this link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth.

The code below creates keypairs, and they work with snowflake/snowflake connector for python.  It is lightly modified from examples in the cryptography documents that create other formats.

Questions:

1. The standard python "cryptography" manual cautions about people like me who don't understand cryptography messing around with hazmat libraries.  Do you see anything relevant to security problem with the way I am generating keys?  Assuming I can securely get them from point of generation to the place where they are used, is this okay?
2. Would it be safer automate by running openssl in a subprocess, using the Snowflake documented procedures?

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization as crypto_serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend as crypto_default_backend

key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    backend=crypto_default_backend(),
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048
)

private_key = key.private_bytes(
    crypto_serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    crypto_serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    crypto_serialization.NoEncryption()
)

public_key = key.public_key().public_bytes(
    crypto_serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    crypto_serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)

with open("/tmp/pubkey.pub", "wt") as pub:
    pub.write(public_key.decode("utf-8"))

with open("/tmp/privkey.p8", "wt") as priv:
    priv.write(private_key.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: I see no difference in "safety" between the python and the openssl approaches, but why do you want to use python? The openssl approach is less code to maintain and is documented already in the link you provided.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  Thank you.  My first choice (I think) should be to  automate openssl.  I'm not sure if openssl will be available on platforms where I or my platform team are generating keys.  I want to verify there's nothing wrong at the outset with the way I'm using python cryptography.